# problem with time in HadGEM2-ES NetCDF file

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have the file:

tasmin_day_HadGEM2-ES_rcp45_r4i1p1_20151201-20251130.nc

and when I run de code:

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path = r'C:\Users\alexandre\Downloads'
df = xr.open_mfdataset(path + r'\tasmin_day_HadGEM2-ES_rcp45_r4i1p1_20151201-20251130.nc')
plt.figure()
df['tasmin'].isel(lat=100, lon=100).plot(label='plot1')
print(df['tasmin'].time.min())
df['tasmin'].isel(lat=100, lon=100).plot(label='plot2')
print(df['tasmin'].time.min())
plt.legend()
```

I always have differents plots, per example:

[image]

if I look the dates, from print command, I could found:

```
    <xarray.DataArray 'time' ()>
array('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
    height   float64 ...
<xarray.DataArray 'time' ()>
array('2015-12-01T12:00:00.000000000', dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
    height   float64 ...
```

What is really weird, as the data start on 2015-12-01!

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found the answer on xarray [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html) :

Like many real-world datasets, this dataset does not entirely follow CF conventions. Unexpected formats will usually cause xarray’s automatic decoding to fail. The way to work around this is to either set decode_cf=False in open_dataset to turn off all use of CF conventions, or by only disabling the troublesome parser. In this case, we set decode_times=False because the time axis here provides the calendar attribute in a format that xarray does not expect (the integer 360 instead of a string like '360_day').

So, just change the line:

```
df = xr.open_mfdataset(path + r'\tasmin_day_HadGEM2-ES_rcp45_r4i1p1_20151201-20251130.nc'
```

to

```
df = xr.open_mfdataset(path + r'\tasmin_day_HadGEM2-ES_rcp45_r4i1p1_20151201-20251130.nc', decode_times=False)
```